# Отправка E-Mail из приложения Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу сделать в своем приложении отправку E-mail по клику из меню. Использую QDesktopServices. По ссылке переходит, а вот mailto не работает. 
Пишу так:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("mailto:receiver@outlook.com"));
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Может не установлена почтовая программа(outlook, the bat и т.д.), которая бы подхватывала ссылку или в настройках Windows не выставлена соответствующая программа по-умолчанию.

Answer (score -1):

Должно работать, проблема видимо где-то в системе, попробуйте ввести

```
mailto:receiver@outlook.com
```

прямо в адресную строку браузера

Comment: если я ввожу в строку браузера, то почта Outlook  открывается, а из приложения никак.

Comment: а в окне Application Output (если qtcreator) что-то ругается на openUrl?

Comment: это linux? я как-то встречал, что на некоторых сочетаниях линуксов и Qt версий такое встречается, именно на mailto